# MS Access remove any lines with duplicate emails

Tags: sql, email, ms-access

This is infuriating because there should be some easy way to do this but there doesn't seem to be.

I have a huge query with several fields and many rows, one column contains a user email.

However sometimes there are duplicates -- two rows that have the same email (and may have some or all other fields in their rows different, or the same, etc).

It doesn't matter to me which rows I eliminate, but I want to eliminate any rows that have duplicate emails. I only want to ensure that an email shows up once in the entire query, period.

For example if I had

```
A A A A Email1
A B A A Email1
K D S F Email1
A A K A Email2
A A K A Email2
A B B A Email2
A C D A Email2
A B B A Email2
K A V D Email2
```

where letters = arbitrary fields and Email# represents an email, then I need it to go to

```
A A A A Email1
A A K A Email2
```

Can this be done in MS Access?

Comment: Two choices - 1) use a group by query just on the email address, or 2) use a group by on email and select First (or Max, or Min) of all the other fields if you want unique emails and really don't care which value shows up for the other fields.

Comment: Perhaps `SELECT DISTINCT EmailField FROM HugeQuery` ...?

Comment: I can't use a groupby query on just the email address because then i lose all the other fields -- and if I include the fields, then the groupy is useless anyway due to the variegation of the other fields -- I basically need to do the equivalent of scanning down the rows and kicking out any row that has an email already seen

Comment: For example this does not work: `SELECT Table1.field1, Table1.field2, Table1.field3, Table1.field4, Min(Table1.email) AS MinOfemail
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.field1, Table1.field2, Table1.field3, Table1.field4;`

Comment: *"I can't use a groupby query on just the email address because then i lose all the other fields"* - but you've already said that you don't care what's in the other fields and there may be discrepancies between two rows with the same email address. So why do you need these other fields since they seem to be just garbage placeholders?

Comment: Because I need the fields for at least one email. If all I needed were the emails then I would just do a select distinct email query and be done with it. But I need the fields for at least one email, hence this question

Comment: You misunderstood the suggestion - try select email, min(field1), min(field2), etc GROUP BY email.  This gives you one row for each email, with one item selected from the source data for each other field

Comment: Ahhh gotcha. That does work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using an aggregate subquery in `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT t.Fld1, t.Fld2, t.Fld3, t.Fld4, t.Email
FROM TableName As t
WHERE t.ID IN
   (SELECT Min(sub.ID)
    FROM TableName As sub
    GROUP BY sub.Email);

-- Fld1   Fld2   Fld3   Fld4    Email
--    A      A      A      A    Email1
--    A      A      K      A    Email2
```

An alternative is to use MS Access' [First()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177902%28v=office.12%29.aspx) aggregate function but do note the warning:

> Because records are usually returned in no particular order (unless
>   the query includes an ORDER BY clause), the records returned by these
>   functions will be arbitrary.

```
SELECT First(t.Fld1) AS First_Fld1, First(t.Fld2) AS First_Fld2, 
       First(t.Fld3) AS First_Fld3, First(t.Fd4) AS First_Fld4, 
       t.Email
FROM TableName As t
GROUP BY t.Email
ORDER BY t.ID;
```